# How do I write a complex Excel 2013 "and" "or" function

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I've got a decently long excel formula I need help with. I have a spreadsheet of roughly `5600 rows` of the same repeating ~73 items. In each set, though, not all 73 are present.

I need to fill in a 3rd column with data that corresponds to the first two column.

The formula I have is roughly this:

> =IF(OR(AND(C61="Rundersnippers",D61="Naam product"),"BP1001_RS"), (AND(C61="Rundersnippers",D61="Naam Leverancier"),"BP1002_RS"),
>   (AND(C61="Rundersnippers",D61="Plaats leverancier"),"BP1003_RS"),
>   (AND(C61="Rundersnippers",D61="EG nr. op verpakking"),"BP1004_RS"),

Excel doesn't like this too much. How can I fix it?

Comment: I have written some huge, complex formulae in Excel with no problems. What is the error message you receive?

Comment: "We found a problem with this formula. Try clicking..." The pretty standard one.

If not that, I've gotten either #VALUE! or #NAME?

Comment: Your parentheses are not lining up correctly. Try breaking it down into small chunks using some temporary scratch cells until you get the correct answer. You can then combine the separate conditions in the separate scratch cells, one at a time, until you have the whole formula built.

Comment: I've come up with this:
=IF(OR
(AND(C61="Rundersnippers",D61="Naam product"),"BP1001_RS"), (AND(C61="Rundersnippers",D61="Naam Leverancier"),"BP1002_RS"), (AND(C61="Rundersnippers",D61="Plaats leverancier"),"BP1003_RS"), (AND(C61="Rundersnippers",D61="EG nr. op verpakking"),"BP1004_RS"))

Comment: Should I be using semi-colons rather than commas?

Comment: Your condition for the IF is `OR(AND(C61="Rundersnippers",D61="Naam product"),"BP1001_RS")`, but what can OR do with a non-boolean like `"BP1001_RS"`? That's what I mean by breaking it down into chunks so that you can test each piece individually.

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand how to put in a 'then' statement, if you will. I would like it to be this in essence:

If Cell1 is RS and Cell2 is Name, return BP1   
OR  
If Cell1 is RS and Cell2 is Plant, return BP2.  
  
I'm not sure if I know how to properly ask my question, I guess.

Comment: Sorry, I can't write your formula for you since I don't have your data, and I don't know precisely what you are expecting. Most Windows applications, including Excel, have a wonderful feature that appears when you press the <F1> key.

Comment: I appreciate your help Ron. I used the help feature, but it hasn't helped me out very much which is why I came to superuser.

I don't know how to explain myself as I've never posted on superuser before. Perhaps I'll find another website.

Comment: Looking at your formula, it looks like you don't want the `OR`, but maybe you want nested `IF`s. There is a limit to nesting `IF`, but I don't know what it is off the top of my head. The formula that you list shouldn't exceed that limit if you remove the `OR` and place the next `IF` in the `ELSE` part of the previous `IF`.

Comment: Use a separate lookup table for the replacement texts. First column would be the concatination of column C ("RS") and D ("Plaats") values of your data, second column would be the replacement ("BP1005_RS"). Then you can use a simple `VLOOKUP` function in your data table instead of a convoluted `IF`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using invalid syntax.

The first thing wrong with your formula is the `OR()` statement. The `OR()` statement works the same way as the `AND()` statement, except it returns true if ANY condition is met -opposed to ALL conditions being met. From the example above, it is unnecessary and should be removed.

The second thing wrong with you formula is that you are incorrectly nesting `IF()` statements (or more accurately NOT including them at all). The syntax for an `IF()` statement is:

```
=IF([logic_test], [value_if_true], [value_if_false])
```

To nest an `IF()` statement, you would write an additional `IF()` statement in place of the `[value_if_false]` parameter. i.e.

```
=IF([logic_test], [value_if_true],
   IF([logic_test], [value_if_true], [value_if_false])
 )
```

Your formula, from above, should look like:

```
=IF(AND(C61="Rundersnippers", D61="Naam product"), "BP1001_RS",
   IF(AND(C61="Rundersnippers", D61="Naam Leverancier"), "BP1002_RS",
     IF(AND(C61="Rundersnippers", D61="Plaats leverancier"), "BP1003_RS",
       // And so on..
     )
   )
 )
```

**However**, I would strongly advise rethinking your approach. A good rule of thumb is: If the formula is laboriously repetitive, you are doing something wrong.

Consider combining the values of column A & B (`=A1&"-"&B1`), then indexing the values from a separate table. i.e.

`Data`

```
| Foo            | Bar                | Baz       |
| -------------- | ------------------ | --------- |
| Rundersnippers | Naam product       |           |
| Rundersnippers | Naam Leverancier   |           |
| Rundersnippers | Plaats leverancier |           |
```

`Index`

```
| Index                             | Value     |
| --------------------------------- | --------- |
| Rundersnippers-Naam product       | BP1001_RS |
| Rundersnippers-Naam Leverancier   | BP1002_RS |
| Rundersnippers-Plaats leverancier | BP1003_RS |
```

Then in your `Data` tab, use `=VLOOKUP(A2&"-"&B2, Index!A:B, 2, FALSE)` to find the corresponding value.